# Default UITabController with Contact list

Tags: iphone, contacts

I have a UITabviewController with 3 tab bar items pointing to there own different class, so what I did is to one of the tab bar item class, I have declared the code to display the contact list from the iPhone, it is displaying the contact list when I'm pressing the particular tab for which I have declared the class that should display the contact list, but it is covering the whole view of the iPhone SDK. However I want the bottom bar of tabviewcontroller to be displayed to navigate to other tabs also at the same time.
It is displaying like this

[image]
But I need to display like this

[image]

Comment: skaffman, you have edited this post, any help from you regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

Just Drag and drop tabbarcontroller on your mainwindow xib,Then Add more view cotrollers as you need I think 4 you need Then Make your 3rd viewcontroller as navigationcontroller,Then Expand this navigation controller and select Viewcontroller then open attributes for that and choose your controller file that you coded for contacts and also choose nib file which you designed earlier Then, Set IBOUTLET for tabbarcontroller and navController to delegate.Also synthesize properties for both to use these on other classes.

in Appdelegate.h file

```
    IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBarController;
IBOutlet UINavigationController *navController;
```

In Appdelegate.m file modify applicationDidFinishLaunch method

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Add the navigation controller's view to the window and display.
    [self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```